# Does android.os.Trace Class in Android Framework Have Limitations on its Import ?

Tags: android, android-framework

My application requires a method to be accessed from a class Trace.java, which is present in the package android.os.Trace. I have added the appropriate import statement in order to do this. But the build system shows an error mentioning that 'Trace class not found'. 
But surprisingly the methods of some other classes in the same package, i.e. android.os are at all accessible. Would anyone address about this anomaly ?

Or is it due to limitations imposed on importing of this Trace.java class by android build system?

I am not using Android SDK but building the app directly along with along with JB source tree. The root directory of app has been put at the proper location in the android source tree.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sources of the class. If a method in the documentation has tag `@hide` then this method will be not included into SDK and, thus, will be not available for your application. However, I think you can call this method using reflection (if there is no security checks implemented for it).